# Why is String Templating Better Than String Concatenation from an Engineering Perspective?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I once read (I think it was in "Programming Pearls") that one should use templates instead of building the string through the use of concatenation.

For example, consider the template below (using C# razor library)

```
<in a properties file>
Browser Capabilities
Type = @Model.Type
Name = @Model.Browser
Version = @Model.Version
Supports Frames = @Model.Frames
Supports Tables = @Model.Tables
Supports Cookies = @Model.Cookies
Supports VBScript = @Model.VBScript
Supports Java Applets = @Model.JavaApplets
Supports ActiveX Controls = @Model.ActiveXControls
```

and later, in a separate code file

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    BrowserInfoTemplate = Properties.Resources.browserInfoTemplate; // see above
    string browserInfo = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(BrowserInfoTemplate, browser);
    ...
}
```

From a software engineering perspective, how is this better than an equivalent string concatentation, like below:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
    string s = "Browser Capabilities\n"
        + "Type = "                    + browser.Type + "\n"
        + "Name = "                    + browser.Browser + "\n"
        + "Version = "                 + browser.Version + "\n"
        + "Supports Frames = "         + browser.Frames + "\n"
        + "Supports Tables = "         + browser.Tables + "\n"
        + "Supports Cookies = "        + browser.Cookies + "\n"
        + "Supports VBScript = "       + browser.VBScript + "\n"
        + "Supports JavaScript = "     + 
            browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + "\n"
        + "Supports Java Applets = "   + browser.JavaApplets + "\n"
        + "Supports ActiveX Controls = " + browser.ActiveXControls 
              + "\n"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Which one would *you* rather look at and maintain?

Comment: I think it just boils down to cleaner code. Not sure there's some fundamental software engineering principle at play here.

Comment: @univerio - The most significant engineering-esque difference I see is that the template is not coupled to "HttpBrowserCapabilities".  Surely that's significant from an engineering perspective?

Comment: Swap string concatenation to StringBuilder appends and you'll receive no complaints from me. Purely as a point of personal taste, I find templates are worse for readability and thus maintenance.

Comment: string is immutable and hence the amount of garbage produced after this single assign statement is high try using String builder other string manipulation datastructures

Comment: @linodh & lzcd:  Curious: Is that so? I thought since it is just __one assignment__ there would not be any overhead..??

Comment: e.g. string str= "a"+"b" creates a new string and leaves "a" and "b" for garbage collection

Comment: @lzcd why do you think that templates are worse for readability and maintenance?

Comment: @deostroll I think you're right.  How do I migrate this question to that website?

Comment: Most people just delete and start over. But here I am not sure whats best. You should ask on meta how to handle this?

Comment: So I've decided to flag my own question to see if one of the moderators will migrate it; that way people's answers will be preserved.

Comment: @lzcd "_Swap string concatenation to StringBuilder appends ..._" - even better, use `String.Format()`.

Comment: Not a big fan of string.Format for such purposes either... albeit for different reasons. Anything more than a trivial example and suddenly its a pain to read / work out whats actually being printed. e.g. string.format("{5}:{3} {7} {4}"...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The engineering principles at play here are readability and [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself).

The primary driver of readability is length. Shorter code is more readable (for readers of adequate skill level), so the first case reads better.

A secondary driver is clutter. The absence of punctuation and extraneous characters favours the first case.

The DRY point here is that symbols such as `browser` and `\n` are concealed in the abstraction in case 1, and repeated in case 2. If either of those needed to be changed there would be less places to change in case 1 than case 2.

Set against this is WYSIWYG. In the first case there is something missing between the code you see and how it is put to work, where in the second case all the machinery is plain to see.

[At the opinion level, I would strongly favour case 1; others would not. But that would make this an opinion-based question and it might get closed, so we wouldn't want to venture there.]

Comment: I see it this way: abstracting permits coding in domain terms, abstraction embiggens re-usability; thoughtful abstracting at all code levels effectively "pushes details down"; layered abstracting seems to naturally evolve code to the single responsibility principle; SIP tends to manage and distribute overall code complexity. Thus any given bit of code tends to be easer to read, easier to understand, easier to modify, easier to test. But one must "begin in the basement" with applying OO principles.